# Querying In-App Purchase Info For My Other Apps

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm developing `UWP` apps, say `App2`.

In this apps, I want to check if user already purchase some add-on in my existing apps e.g `App1`.

Can I do this in `UWP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this apps, I want to check if user already purchase some add-on in my existing apps e.g App1

No, this is not possbile to implement. In UWP apps, we will use the [StoreContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext?view=winrt-22621) to perform store related features. All the methods and members from the **StoreContext** object is limited to access Microsoft Store-related data for the current app.